# Writing dynamic css values inview for episerver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to edit a view in EPIserver. I want to allow our users to define the width of embedded YouTube videos. I have created a new form field which needs to be filled out and then I use that value as the percentage width of my "sizer" class.

I had the following view originally:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sizer">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
                            src=@Model.VideoURL
                            frameborder="0"
                            allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                            @Model.AllowFullScreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then I put together some logic in order to dynamically create a style attribute only if the variable is filled.

My idea was to do the following:

```
@{ 

    var SizerStyle = ""; 
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CustomVideoWidthPercent)) {
        SizerStyle = "style=\"width:";  
        SizerStyle += @Model.CustomVideoWidthPercent;
        SizerStyle += "%; margin: 0 auto\"";


    }
```

}

But when I combine the two like so:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sizer" @SizerStyle>
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
                            src=@Model.VideoURL
                            frameborder="0"
                            allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                            @Model.AllowFullScreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I get this in the browser:

```
<div class="sizer" style="50.6%;" margin="" 0="" auto="&quot;>
```

I don't understand what is going on here. It seems there is some logic here to intercept and process css/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print it without any HTML encoding:

```
<div class="sizer" @Html.Raw(SizerStyle)>
```

Everything you print in a Razor view is automatically encoded, unless it implements IHtmlString or is a MvcHtmlString.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am a total c#, Razor, ASP.net newbie